# How to create a relationship between a column of string and a word list in python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, relationship, matching

I have a table with ID and a column of string, in order to create a visual I need to create a relationship between these two sets of information. I wonder if there is a way to do this. Any suggestions? Many thanks!

I have a table, something like below:

[image]

and I have a word list:

[image]

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into dictionaries.

```
dict_table = {"English": [1,4], "Business": 1, "Math": [2,3], "music": 2, ...}
```

or the other way around:

```
dict_table = {1: ["English", "Business"], 2: ["Math", "music"], ...}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for suggestions, I will try it.